# How can I use clipboard.js with importmap in rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, clipboard.js, import-maps

I want to add a **Copy to Clipboard** button to my page in a Ruby on Rails 7 project.

`config/importmap.rb`:

```
pin "clipboard.js", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2.0.10/dist/clipboard.min.js", preload: true
```

`app/javascript/application.js`:

```
import { ClipboardJS } from "clipboard.js"

...

document.addEventListener('turbo:load', (event) => {
  new ClipboardJS('.js-clipboard', {
    text: function(trigger) {
      return trigger.getAttribute('data-clipboard-text')
    }
  })
})
```

But after page loads I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: ClipboardJS
```

- Rails 7.0.2.3
- Ruby 3.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi try to install clipboard by using the command

```
bin/importmap pin clipboard
```

Then instead of importing the module ClipboardJS by using `import { ClipboardJS } from "clipboard.js"`, import just the class this way:

```
import ClipboardJS from 'clipboard'
```

Everything else is correct.